# jQuery UI datepicker check format

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have to restrict users so that they can enter only date in these formats:

```
010611
01062011
01-06-2011
01/06/2011
01jun11
01jun2011
```

Is there any API function for it, or should I use a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same requirement. I solved it by using the [input mask plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/inputmask) for jQuery.

Here you can define the proper format via a regular expression.

Comment: thanks. But again how can i add multiple mask. i.e. for 01062011 & 01/06/2001.

Comment: hm i maybe this is not working if you use an inputmask. so probably in your case it is better to only use an validator and inform the user if he use a wrong format